# Pandas Dataframe fill column with sequence_id based on multiple columns ids and timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*Im editing the df given it contained a typo in ne1_id

having a really hard time trying to solve the following, ill really much appreciate any assistance or light with the following
I have a DataFrame df that looks like this:

|  | timestamp | user_id | ne1_id. | ne2_id. | attempt_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18:11:42.838363 | 1 | 100 |  | 1 |
| 1 | 18:11:42.838364 |  | 100 | 123456 |  |
| 2 | 18:11:42.838365 |  | 100 | 123456 |  |
| 3 | 18:11:42.83836 |  | 100 | 123456 |  |
| 4 | 18:11:45.838365 | 1 | 100 |  | 2 |
| 5 | 18:11:45.838366 |  | 100 | 321234 |  |
| 6 | 18:11:45.838369 |  | 100 | 321234 |  |
| 7 | 18:11:46.838363 | 3 | 12 |  | 3 |
| 8 | 18:11:46.838364 |  | 12 | 9832 |  |
| 9 | 18:11:47.838363 | 2 | 12 |  | 4 |
| 10 | 18:11:47.838369 |  | 100 |  |  |

What I want to do is to fill the attempt_no of the empty cells (empties are empties not NaN) for the next rows based on timestamp (or index) with the proper attempt_no  by associating user_id, ne1_id, ne2_id associations,
I im not seeing the logic of it neither the way of do it.

the result should be something like this

|  | timestamp | user_id | ne1_id. | ne2_id. | attempt_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18:11:42.838363 | 1 | 100 |  | 1 |
| 1 | 18:11:42.838364 |  | 100 | 123456 | 1 |
| 2 | 18:11:42.838365 |  | 100 | 123456 |  |
| 3 | 18:11:42.838369 |  | 100 | 123456 |  |
| 4 | 18:11:45.838365 | 1 | 100 |  | 2 |
| 5 | 18:11:45.838366 |  | 100 | 321234 | 2 |
| 6 | 18:11:45.838369 |  | 100 | 321234 |  |
| 7 | 18:11:46.838363 | 3 | 12 |  | 3 |
| 8 | 18:11:46.838364 |  | 12 | 9832 | 3 |
| 9 | 18:11:47.838363 | 2 | 12 |  | 4 |
| 10 | 18:11:47.838369 |  | 100 |  | 4 |

something that says the following:
"find all the rows where there is a user_id and find the next row with the same ne1_id with an empty user_id and attemp_no and fill atppemp_no with the attemp_no of the previous row"
i tried with groupby -that i believe is the way of do it-, but kind of stuck there

i appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: df.attempt_no.mask(df.attempt_no.eq('')).fillna(method='ffill')??

Comment: You haven't defined how attempts are associated. Currently it looks like forward fill attempt_no and reset the index. It's also unclear if those are spaces or NaN in the columns. Please provide your dataframe as a _copyable_ piece of code. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information.

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks, i just edited with that context. those are just spaces, not NaN. Either way i hand shared the proper ne_id2 (network element#2), that eventually would be needed to associate all the columns with the proper attemp_no that i need.

Comment: @Nk03 thanks pal, that was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```py
def f(x):
    last = None
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if np.isnan(x[i]):
            x[i] = last
        else:
            last = x[i]
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, None, None, 2, None, None, None, 3, None]})
df[['x']].apply(f)
```

By applying the function on `axis=0` you are able to jointly process the entire column.